# Objeto não pode ser convertido de DBNull em outros tipos

Tags: vb.net

De alguns dias para cá, todas as minhas aplicações em VB.NEt, utilizo o visual studio 2022, pararam de funcionar de uma hora para a outra, em um dia estava tudo rodando perfeito e no outro dia literalmente, começou a apresentar o erro 'Objeto não pode ser convertido de DBNull em outros tipos' utilizo Mysql, segue um código simples para teste de conexão, onde apresenta o eventual erro.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim connectionString As String = "Server= ******;Uid=*******;Pwd=*********;Database=*********;sslMode=none"

        Try
            Using conexao As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
                conexao.Open()
                MessageBox.Show("Conexão Ok")
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

[Imagem do Erro Objeto não pode ser convertido de DBNull em outros tipos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnDwR.png)

Comment: Parece mais um problema de infraestrutura do que um problema de linguagem de programação. Houveram modificações ou alterações administrativas na rede, ou alteração/upgrade de hardware, ou alterações/upgrade de software? Pergunto pois olhando o código junto da mensagem de erro leva a entender que a string de conexão usada não é mais adequada.

Comment: Isso é problema com os dados do seu banco de dados. Recomendo averiguar e observar se seus valores ainda estão lá. Observe se pacotes foram atualizados, junto com frameworks e bibliotecas, pois as vezes podem quebrar uma coisa ou outra no meio de uma atualização inesperada. De qualquer forma, a pergunta requer mais detalhes para continuar averiguando.